# Can't boot Windows 7 from USB, GRUB still there

Tags: windows-7, live-usb, bootloader, grub-efi

I need to install Win 7 on a computer that previously had Ubuntu 14.04 installed. I created a bootable USB with the Windows 7 ISO on it, but I can't boot from it. From the BIOS/UEFI (not sure) I select the USB stick as boot device but it will not boot but go directly into GRUB.

When I put my Ubuntu USB in, I can boot Ubuntu directly without going to GRUB. I'm really an amateur when it comes to Linux, but I wonder what I can do to repair my boot routine for booting the Windows 7 USB and install it?

[My partitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Qlf3.png)

Comment: Windows 7 default is BIOS which only works on MBR partitioned drives. If you want UEFI boot and drive is gpt partitioned you have to slightly modify Windows 7 flash drive to have boot files in correctly location for UEFI boot. Both Ubuntu & Windows need to be in same boot mode, both UEFI or both BIOS.http://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-can-i-create-a-windows-bootable-usb-stick-using-ubuntu and: http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/15458-uefi-bootable-usb-flash-drive-create-windows.html

Comment: I already deleted my Ubuntu partitions. I can't find a way to boot Windows 7 from the USB stick, while booting Ubuntu Live from USB works. What might be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that the problem is your burned USB for Windows. Maybe try to burn a new one by using the official application provide by Microsoft named **Windows USB/DVD Download Tool.**

And just a trick: you could try your usb key to see if it's bootable by testing it on a Virtualbox's VM. To do that when you start a VM on the first seconds you see the text "**press F12 to select the boot device**". You certainly  need to boot a first time to mount the USB on the VM by going on Devices > Usb > NAMEOFYOURUSB. Then, you shutdown/start to press F12 the second time.

Comment: I created it with Rufus, but I will try again with the official Microsoft app. How can I use a VM to check whether it's bootable?

Comment: I edited my  answer  to explain how to check with Virtualbox

Comment: Created an USB stick with the official Microsoft app, still cannot boot. Installed Oracle VM Virtualbox now and it doesn't prompt me to select the boot device. I can't seem to mount the USB.